# Query para contar dependências de tabela

Tags: sql

Vamos supor que tenho uma banco de dados com somente 50 tabelas.

Na estrutura, tenho várias ligações, diversas chaves estrangeiras.

**Existe uma forma, de forma de fazer um query que traga a quantidade de dependências de todas tabelas do banco** ?

Por exemplo:

- A tabela ZZZ tem FK da tabela XXX e YYY
- A tabela XXX tem FK da tabela WWW
- A tabela WWW não tem FK

Resultado esperado:

```
tabela | dependencias
 ZZZ   |      2
 XXX   |      1
 WWW   |      0
```

Comment: sim, qual o banco de dados?

Comment: Cara... qualquer um... se puder até colocar nos mais comuns: sql-server, mysql, etc... legal que mantém uma pergunta já para vários... fica um registro bem útil...

Comment: via ferramenta no `sql server` você pode no *management studio* ver as dependências, e no `mysql` o *TOAD* tem a mesma função, agora como query, vou colocar como uma resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `SQL-SERVER` você pode linkar a tabela `foreign_keys` com a table `sysobjects` para isso:

```
 SELECT
   s.name,
   count(f.name) Dependencias
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f
INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects s
   ON f.parent_object_id = s.id
group by s.name
ORDER BY s.name
```

No `MySQL` pode ser assim, usando a tabela table_constraints:

```
select distinct ref.referenced_table_name Tabela,
       count(ref.referenced_table_name) Dependencias
  from information_schema.table_constraints tab
 inner join information_schema.referential_constraints ref
    on tab.constraint_name = ref.constraint_name
group by ref.referenced_table_name
order by ref.referenced_table_name;
```

Criei um fiddle para exemplificar: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36ccc0/1